# "cette poire a l'air mauvais" or "cette poire a l'air mauvaise"

Tags: grammaire

> Cette poire a l'air **mauvais / mauvaise**, jette-la.

I’m not sure if the adjective following the "air" should take the masculine or feminine form.

Should the adjective correspond to the masculine noun "air" or the feminine subject "poire"? The same goes for the following.

> Elle a l'air **fatigué / fatiguée**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complete the previous answer, *avoir l'air* is an attributive verb, like *être* (be), *devenir* (become), *paraître*, *sembler*, etc. With such verbs, what comes after (adjective) is the attribute and therefore agrees with the subject.

> Cette dame a l'air perdue. (*This lady seems lost*)
>
> Cette dame est perdue. (*This lady is lost*)

Of course, sometimes, *avoir l'air* can be the verb *avoir* plus the direct object *l'air*. In that case, the adjective agrees with what it completes, in that case the noun *air*.

> Ces hommes ont l'air bêtes. (*These men seem mean*)
>
> Ces hommes ont l'air bête. (*These men have a dumb look*)

Comment: Pour compléter la réponse précédente, avoir l'air est un verbe attributif, tout comme *être*, *devenir*, *paraître*, *sembler*, etc. Dans ces cas-là, ce qui suit (nom ou adjectif) est probablement l'attribut du sujet et donc s'accorde avec le sujet.

Bien sûr, il arrive parfois qu'il s'agisse plutôt du verbe *avoir* et de son complément direct *l'air*. Dans ce cas, l'adjective s'accorde avec ce dernier.

Answer (score 1):

In your sentences, *mauvais* and *fatigué* apply to *poire* and *elle*. One should then say:

- Cette poire a l'air mauvaise. (That pear looks bad)
- Elle à l'air fatiguée. (She looks tired, she seems to be tired)

On the opposite, when the adjective applies to *air* and *elle* is a person, not an object, it should stay masculine:

- Elle a l'air mauvais. (She looks nasty, she has a nasty face))

but

- Elle a l'air mauvaise. (She looks ungifted, she doesn't seem to be skilled)

---

Mauvais et fatigué se rapportent à la poire et à « elle », on dira donc:

- Cette poire a l'air mauvaise.
- Elle à l'air fatiguée.

En revanche, quand l'adjectif se rapporte à air et que « elle » se rapporte à une personne, pas un objet, il ne doit pas y avoir d'accord :

- Elle a l'air mauvais. (Sa physionomie est désagréable)

mais

- Elle a l'air mauvaise. (Elle ne semble ne pas être douée)